# Search and replace in textarea java

Tags: java, replace, textarea

There is nothing wrong with replacing except that after I replace what I want to replace all the other strings on the textarea suddenly turns into lowercase how could I fix it

```
     replacebutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String txt = textArea.getText().toLowerCase();
            String txt2 = search.getText().toLowerCase();
            String txt3 = replace.getText();

            if (txt.contains(txt2)) {
                textArea.setText(txt.replaceAll(txt2, txt3));

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set back the txt variable that you set to lowercase before. Thats why everything is lowercase after this procedure.

You can replace insensitive with:

```
String.replaceAll("(?i)" + toReplace, Replacement);
```

Use it like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String txt = textArea.getText();
    String txt2 = search.getText();
    String txt3 = replace.getText();

    if (txt.toLowerCase().contains(txt2.toLowerCase())) {
            textArea.setText(txt.replaceAll("(?i)" + txt2, txt3));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the sudden lowerCase is that you call toLowercase on the textArea.GetText(). The txt variable now holds a all lowercase string. Then you call the textArea.setText(txt...

You can try this:

```
String txt = textArea.getText();
String txt2 = search.getText();
String txt3 = replace.getText();

if (txt.contains(txt2)) {
     textArea.setText(txt.replaceAll(txt2, txt3));
}
```

(however you will not have a case-insensitive search and replace..)